# Select entries in relation to fields in another table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables, Table1 shows all users, and Table2 shows a teacher-to-student relationship:

Table1 (users):

```
ID  name  age
-------------
1   Al    30
2   Bob   5
3   Cam   6
4   Dan   7
```

Table2 (classes):

```
teacher_id  student_id 
----------------------
1           2
1           3
```

Essentially, this shows Al (id=1) is the teacher of Bob (id=2) and also Cam (id=3). I want to return users rows of a teacher and his students. For example, if I'm looking for Al (id=1), I want to return users info of Al and his students (Bob and Cam). What I thought was

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN classes ON users.id=classes.teacher_id 
  WHERE id=1 OR teacher_id=1
```

But I know it must be wrong because "teacher_id=1" doesn't get values from classes.student_id. It should be "... WHERE id={the student_id's from classes where teacher_id=1}". How do you do this?

Comment: Users are joined to each field separately and independently. So you need 2 separate users table copies - one will be joined to classes via teacher_id and another via student_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Query like this to show the students search by teachers name.

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
where u.id IN (
    SELECT t.student_id 
    FROM classes t 
    LEFT JOIN users tu ON t.`teacher_id` = tu.id
    WHERE tu.name = 'Al'
    );
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from users;
+----+------+------+
| id | name | age  |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | Al   |   30 |
|  2 | Bob  |    5 |
|  3 | Cam  |    6 |
|  4 | Dan  |    7 |
+----+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * FROM classes;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | teacher_id | student_id |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          2 |
|  2 |          1 |          3 |
+----+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT u.* FROM users u
    -> where u.id IN (
    ->     SELECT t.student_id
    ->     FROM classes t
    ->     LEFT JOIN users tu ON t.`teacher_id` = tu.id
    ->     WHERE tu.name = 'Al'
    ->     );
+----+------+------+
| id | name | age  |
+----+------+------+
|  2 | Bob  |    5 |
|  3 | Cam  |    6 |
+----+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT * FROM classes 
LEFT JOIN user ON classes.teacher_id= users.id
WHERE classes.teacher_id=1 or user.id = 1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can join `classes` to 2 copies of `users`:

```
select u1.name teacher, u2.name student
from classes c
inner join users u1 on u1.id = c.teacher_id
inner join users u2 on u2.id = c.student_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xvbihmXWwSmEyM4Vvf1ts4/0).
Results:

```
| teacher | student |
| ------- | ------- |
| Al      | Bob     |
| Al      | Cam     |
```

Or if you want a comma separated list of all the students of each teacher:

```
select u1.name teacher, group_concat(u2.name) students
from classes c
inner join users u1 on u1.id = c.teacher_id
inner join users u2 on u2.id = c.student_id
group by teacher
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xvbihmXWwSmEyM4Vvf1ts4/1).
Results:

```
| teacher | students |
| ------- | -------- |
| Al      | Bob,Cam  |
```